# Python and mysql login form

Tags: python, mysql, authentication, mysql-python

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import *
 import os
 from tkinter import messagebox
 from PIL import ImageTk , Image
 import mysql.connector
     mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="welcome123456",database="moonsun_hospital")
 cursor=mydb.cursor()
 cursor.execute("create database if not exists moonsun_hospital")
 cursor.execute("use moonsun_hospital")
#cursor.execute("create table if not exists login_table(username varchar(15),password varchar(30))")




 

def login():
  global login
  login_screen=Toplevel()
  login_screen.maxsize(450,300)
  login_screen.title('Account Login')
  login_screen.config(bg="white")
  login_screen.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Moonsun hospital\background\hospital-2_icon-    icons.com_66067.ico")
  login_screen_img =ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Moonsun     hospital\background\background.jpeg"))
  lb2 = Label(login_screen,image =login_screen_img)
  lb2.image =login_screen_img
  lb2.pack()
  Label(login_screen, text="USERNAME").place(x=210,y=100)
  username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable="username")
  username_login_entry.place(x=180,y=125)
  Label(login_screen, text="PASSWORD").place(x=210,y=150)
  password__login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable="password", show= '*')
  password__login_entry.place(x=180,y=175)
  def OK():
    username=username_login_entry.get()
    password=password__login_entry.get()
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="welcome123456",database="moonsun_hospital")
    cursor=mydb.cursor()
    savequery="select * from Login_table"
    cursor.execute(savequery)
    myresult=cursor.fetchall()
    for i in myresult:
      if username in i and password in i:
        messagebox.showinfo("LOGIN",'LOGIN SUCCESSFUL')
        #moonsun_main.py()
      else:
        messagebox.showerror("LOGIN ERROR","LOGIN ERROR")
        mydb.commit()
      cursor.close()
      mydb.close()
        #moonsun_register.py()
  Button(login_screen,text="Login", height=1, width=6,bg="#AFF8DB",command=OK).place(x=215 , y = 200 )
```

i count able to execute it....lot of error
the login algorithm isnt working in a proper way
kindly give me some ideas please guys
i tried lot of algorithms but i dont know what is wrong in it
i hope ill get a reply sooner or later

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just let `MySQL` query check the login, its much easier that way:

```py
def OK():
    username = username_login_entry.get()
    password = password__login_entry.get()
    
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="welcome123456",database="moonsun_hospital")
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    
    savequery = "SELECT * FROM Login_table WHERE username=%s AND password=%s" # Get the records with these username and password ONLY
    cursor.execute(savequery,(username,password)) 
    myresult = cursor.fetchall() 
    
    if myresult: # If there is such a record, then success
        messagebox.showinfo("LOGIN",'LOGIN SUCCESSFUL')
        # Whatever you want to do after user is authentic
        new = Toplevel() # To open new window

    else: # Wrong password
        messagebox.showerror("LOGIN ERROR","LOGIN ERROR")
    cursor.close()
    mydb.close()
```

This way you don't have to use much `if` and `for` loops. Here `%s` is called parameters and you are subsituting the values of `username` and `password` instead of it while executing the query, so the query is literally:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Login_table WHERE username='John' AND password='123123'; -- If username is john and password is 123123
```

Comment: but still it only shows login error not login successful

Comment: what shoul i do about it

Comment: @GayuGudiyaa You might be entering it wrong, what is username and password

Comment: actually i created a registration form in that when i register things it shoul get saved in a table.after that i want to check whether that username and password exist in that table...and regarding that if it exist it should show login successful...if not then error

Comment: @GayuGudiyaa Are you sure the data is getting registered to the database?

Comment: brother now it works....i have another doubt....when the login is successful..i want another window to open what shoul i do

Comment: Put everything that you want to do when the login is successful inside of `if myresult:`

Comment: can u give an example brother